# Determining pendulum rise using trigonometry

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Everyone in my math class (including the teacher) is having problems with this trigonometry question: [image: About how far does the tip of a 1.8m pendulum rise as it swings 24 degrees to one side? Round your answer to the nearest hundredth metre.]

I am assuming that you halve the pendulum and the bottom of the triangle would be $\frac{1.8}{2} = 0.9$. Then using $\tan$ you can figure out the rise of the pendulum like below (where $x$ is equal to the rise)?

$$
\tan (24) = \frac{x}{0.9} \\
\frac{0.4452}{1} = \frac{x}{0.9} \\
x = 0.4452 \times 0.9 \\
x = 0.4007 \\
x \approx 0.401
$$

Please let me know if this is right or if I am doing it totally wrong (which I think I am).

Comment: Draw a picture, start with the pendulum completely vertical. That length is 1.8m. Now draw the pendulum from the top tip going 24 degrees to the left or right, from there you can determine the height if you label everything appropriately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the length of the pendulum string is $L$ and the string makes an angle $\theta$ with the vertical, then the vertical distance (from anchor point of the string down the the height of the bob) is
$$
L \cos \theta.
$$
(Do you see why?)

Now, the height of the bob, measured up from the lowest point is
$$
h = L - L \cos \theta = L(1 - \cos \theta).
$$

Now, plug in $L = 1.8$m and $\theta = 24^{\circ}$ to find $h$.

Comment: So then the height is 0.1557 metres?

Comment: Yes, that's approximately it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is commonly seen in Physics problems involving potential energy and pendulums. The height $h$ above the lowest point of the pendulum is given by $h=L(1-\cos \theta)$.

Answer (score 0):

A pendulum swings in the form of an arc, not a triangle.

The length of an arc of radius $r$ and angle $\theta$ is $\theta r$.

In your problem, $r = 1.8m; \theta  = \dfrac {2 \pi} {15} = 24 ^\circ$, so the arc length is $1.8 \dfrac {2 \pi} {15} = 0.753981 \approx 0.8m$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use MathJax for formatting equations. :)